# Unable to install .deb applications with ubuntu software

Tags: 16.04, software-center, atom, gdebi

I'm new to Ubuntu Environment. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I'm learning Web Development my own. I heard some good words about using Linux for Web Dev. So I just dual boot my Windows laptop with Ubuntu. After installation and software update. I visit atom.io to install Atom Text Editor. I downloaded the .deb file. I clicked on it and it took me to Ubuntu Software. I clicked on Install button but nothing happened.
[I also tried to install with terminal and got this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKM9.jpg)

Comment: `Sudo apt-get install gdebi` Ref https://launchpad.net/gdebi

Comment: Also what you posted is not an error, you are just adding a repository.

Comment: But I didn't get the reason why I wasn't able to install by ubuntu software.

Answer (score 0):

you can **install** any deb package by

sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE ,

if there is dependency problem you can solve it

**sudo apt-get -f install**

you can **remove** a package by

sudo dpkg -r PACKAGE_NAME

Comment: Jino Pl : »» you can install any deb package by `sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE` «« → Not if it has depencencies ! ... These commands will also install dependencies : `sudo gdebi ./package.deb` ... and `sudo apt install  ./package.deb`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it via the commandline with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <name of package>.deb
```

Comment: To name is enough or  should I specify the path of it?

Comment: I got this - https://prntscr.com/iktt5p

Comment: Maybe you have to go to the downloads folder? `cd Downloads`

Comment: This happened - https://prntscr.com/iku82q

Comment: That looks like it worked.

Comment: I think its not.